# Tab Layout - NoSuchMethodError on addOnTabSelectedListener

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-studio-3.2

I am testing on API 27, Oreo (Virtual device)

The dependencies added are:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

The error logcat:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method addOnTabSelectedListener(Landroid/support/design/widget/TabLayout$OnTabSelectedListener;)V in class Landroid/support/design/widget/TabLayout; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.design.widget.TabLayout' appears in /data/app/com.not_relevant.not_relevant-N_xBMjVbkq_DVzGjxHFM6Q==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
```

Comment: Invalidating caches and then restarting Android Studio

Comment: @sasikumar already tried, doesn't help.

Comment: your compileSdkVersion ?

Comment: How about updating the support library to : `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` and `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` ?

Comment: @sasikumar compileSdkVersion is 27

Comment: @Mohsen Yes, that worked. Is this a bug in SDK 27?

Comment: @KshitijSaxena Maybe. I've added an answer and you can fill a bug report and report it to google developers however, this happened while `AndroidX` and 28 is available so, you better use latest libraries-dependencies.

Comment: did you get the solution for this issue?? myself also getting the same issue.

Comment: @prakashMp Yes, this occurs because of conflict in support library version. It should work if you update all support libraries to 28.0.0

Comment: yeah, I changed support library version(28) now its working fine. thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can report this issue if you think that is a bug but, updating those libraries helps most of the times:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0' 
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

However, like mentioned, this happened while `AndroidX` and `28.0.0` version is available so you better use latest libraries-dependencies